# C++ static cross-compilation failing on LibCurl and OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, static-libraries, cross-compiling, libcurl

I have a C++ application which depends on both Libcurl (nghttp2 for HTTP/2.0) and OpenSSL to work. However, since I don't want any DLL-dependencies I would like to build my application statically (I have the static libraries). However, I can't get it to work with the underneath command which is cross-compiling from 64-bit Linux for 32-bit Windows, resulting in the errors shown below:

The Build command:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall Programm.cpp -o Programm.exe -I/opt/mingw64/Win32/include -L/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib -I/Software -I/Software/Deps -lcurl -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lcrypto -lssl -lws2_32 -std=c++11 -static -DCURL_STATICLIB
```

results in these errors:

*[REMOVED BECAUSE OF TO LARGE BODY]*

***UPDATE***

I have modified my build command to:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall Programm.cpp -o Programm.exe -I/opt/mingw64/Win32/include -L/Software -I/Software/Deps -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lcurl -lnghttp2 -lssl -lcrypto -DCURL_STATICLIB -lpthread -lws2_32 -std=c++11 -static
```

This leads to the following errors:

```
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x448): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x4ac): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x5d4): more undefined references to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data' follow
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x6ee): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_want_write'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x75e): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_priority_spec_init'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x7e2): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_submit_priority'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x7ef): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_send'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x8d3): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_del'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x94d): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xb43): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xb4e): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_is_fatal'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xb69): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_remote_settings'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xcdb): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xce4): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_is_fatal'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xda8): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xe80): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xeca): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xf6d): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_want_read'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xf87): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_want_write'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0xfc7): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x1036): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x11c5): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_http2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x1298): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_resume_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x12ca): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_is_fatal'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x176c): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_submit_request'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x17bb): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_send'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x17f9): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_resume_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x1d0c): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x1d19): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_is_fatal'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x1f9e): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2037): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_new'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2071): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_send_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2086): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_recv_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x209b): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_invalid_frame_recv_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x20b0): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_data_chunk_recv_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x20c5): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_before_frame_send_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x20da): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_send_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x20ef): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_not_send_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2104): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_stream_close_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2119): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_begin_headers_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x212e): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_header_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2143): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_error_callback'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x215e): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_client_new'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x216d): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_callbacks_del'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x21b7): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x21e7): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x22bc): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_version'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x22f2): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_http2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2510): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2555): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_submit_rst_stream'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2631): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_pack_settings_payload'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2751): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_resume_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x298c): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_submit_settings'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x29bd): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_set_local_window_size'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2a41): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_upgrade'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2a54): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2a85): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2ab5): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2afb): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2b49): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_session_mem_recv'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2b54): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_is_fatal'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2b88): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o):http2.c:(.text+0x2bb5): undefined reference to `_imp__nghttp2_strerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My libCurl build command:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.56.1.tar.gz
tar xf curl-7.56.1.tar.gz 
cd curl-7.56.1/
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/opt/mingw64/Win32 --with-ssl=/opt/mingw64/Win32 --with-nghttp2=/opt/mingw64/Win32 --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps curl_LDFLAGS=-all-static
make
make install
```

My build configuration for LibCurl:

```
curl version:     7.56.1
  Host setup:       i686-w64-mingw32
  Install prefix:   /opt/mingw64/Win32
  Compiler:         i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  enabled
  resolver:         POSIX threaded
  IPv6 support:     enabled
  Unix sockets support: no      (--enable-unix-sockets)
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn2,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
  HTTP2 support:    enabled (nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few link-order errors.  The C and C++ linkers are greedy when using static libraries.  If they don't need a symbol by the time they see it, they prune it away.  This means you have to be somewhat careful about the order you specify libraries on the command-line.  You need to put the consumer .a first, and the supplier .a after.

So, in the section of errors like:

```
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x6da): undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x6f2): undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'
...
```

These come because libcrypto was encountered before libssl (which depends on it).  You can eliminate these by moving `-lssl` before `-lcrypto`.

For the ones like

```
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-asyn-thread.o):asyn-thread.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_destroy'
/opt/mingw64/Win32/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-asyn-thread.o):asyn-thread.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
```

Your libcurl is looking for libpthread, so you need to put `-lpthread` *after* -lcurl.  It looks like libcurl is also looking for an ldap implementation...I'm not really familliar with that, but there's probably a `-lldap` missing somewhere (presuming libldap).  Lastly, I don't see your `nghttp` library anywhere on the command-line.  It looks like it should follow `-lcurl` as well.

That leaves the missing libcurl imports at the top; I don't have any idea there.

Comment: Thanks, both `-lldap` and `-libdap` are not found? Many errors are solved now but I still remain having errors for the `nghttp2` library, while I added this one behind `-lcurl` as `-lnghttp2`? See update on my question

Comment: I'm concerned about the `_imp__` prefix on those missing symbols.  That implies it thinks they are 'imports' (i.e., from a DLL).  Can you confirm that the LDAP and nghttp2 libraries you've linked against are also compiled as static libs?

Comment: nghttp2 is compiled statically (`nghttp2.a`). I haven't done anything with ldap libs. I might build libcurl without `ldap` if this issue can't be resolved?

Comment: It really seems that, while your libcurl.a is built to not need a libcurl.dll, it is using dll-based versions of the libraries that libcurl depends on.

Comment: This article seems to give a solution for makeing libcurl link against static libldap: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/503.  May also affect nghttp2.  Look for the part where they add `curl_LDFLAGS=-all-static` to the make command-line for libcurl

Comment: Right, at the moment I am rebuilding Curl without the ldap support. That should get rid of the errors of ldap. However, how do I fix the nghttp2 related errors? I have added by build configuration of LibCurl in my question

Comment: The new libcurl build is not complaining about the ldap anymore. Only the nghttp2 errors are left as shown above in my updated question

Comment: did you see the comment on `curl_LDFLAGS=-all-static` above?  I'd be curious what effect that has.

Comment: No difference with the `curl_LDFLAGS=-all-static` option enabled. The nghttp2 related errors still appear

Comment: Just stumbled across this: `-DNGHTTP2_STATICLIB` in another context...might be worth a shot on your command-line above.

Comment: No improvement when I add this to the build command... The same errors appear

Comment: The third comment down repros a similar issue, and gives their setup for building libcurl to resolve it. 
https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/503

Comment: They don't use nghttp2? nghttp2 is the only library still giving errors on my build

Comment: Can you give the configure and build commands you use for libcurl?

Comment: Any idea why it keeps failing on the nhgttp2 library? I haven’t been able to find a solution..

Comment: No, sorry.  I was tinkering with trying to repro it locally, but I'm not that good with mingw.

Comment: you might do well to post a new question tagged as [mingw] [autotools] [configure] [libcurl], and give your `configure` and `make` commands (for both libcurl and nghttp2) alongside a few lines of the linker error.  I think this needs someone who really understands autoconf.  Maybe a title like "Static libcurl build not using static versions of dependencies"